# SQL query to get value from referenced table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables called `mg_product` and `mg_product_user_property`. 
In `mg_product` there are 3 columns: `id`, `title`, `price` as

[image]

In `mg_product_user_property` table `product_id` corresponds with `id` column in `mg_product` table.

[image]

So my goal is to get the value of `property_id` of "15", which in the picture above will be "Mediatek".

This is my SQL:

```
$sql = "SELECT *
            FROM mg_product AS products
            INNER JOIN mg_product_user_property AS properties
            ON products.id = properties.product_id
            WHERE title LIKE '%$search%')";`
```

PHP:

```
$resultSet = DB::query($sql);

if ($resultSet->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()) {
        $title = $rows['title'];
        $price = $rows['price'];
    }
} else {
    $output = "No results";
}
```

Now I need to assign to a php variable the value of `property_id=15` so I will be able to print "Mediatek" on my website. How can I achieve that? Sorry for my English.

Comment: Ah, pretty straightforward here... but you realize that join is going to return a whole lot of the same product. You have different directions to go here. Which way is by anyones preference though, so the answers may be varied but result the same.

Comment: If it was me, I'd forget about all the PHP for now, and instead focus on the MySQL. And, accordingly, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close to what you want, but a couple things are going to either be a mess, or unwanted. So, since there are different ways one can go with this, I will only present a very stripped example (and am INTENTIONALLY leaving out a bunch of code here).

You may not want to do a JOIN like that in the initial search, as for each property, it will also return another of the same product. So looping through that will result in dozens of the same product.

However, if _ALL_YOU_WANT_ is to show the Product Title, Price, and Property 15... you can reduce some headwork with a simpler query:

```
SELECT p.title, p.price, pr.value
FROM mg_product AS p
     LEFT JOIN mg_product_user_property AS pr
         ON p.id = pr.product_id AND pr.property_id = 15
WHERE p.title LIKE '%$search%'
```

The LEFT JOIN means if the property doesn't exist, it will still return the product. But with an empty property value. And this should not return dozens of the same product for every other property in the table.

--

The OTHER way you could go about doing it, using the SQL query you already have (and the dozens of results of the same product it will return), you can alter your php loop like so:

```
$found_products = array();
while ($row = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()) {
    if ($row['property_id'] == 15) {
        $found_products[$row['product_id']] = array(
                'title' => $row['title'],
                'price' => $row['price'],
                'prop'  => $row['value']
            );
   }
}
// now you have a clean array of found products that have the property
```

--

*Also I am forced to point out that you should use a prepared statement here, replacing inserting $search directly into the code. But showing you all of how to do that is beyond the scope of this question/answer.*